# xlsxwriter .add_table() set columns works for one dataframe but not the other

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying to add a data table in Excel using python library xlsxwriter

My Dataframe named `whole` has 26 columns (exactly the letters in the alphabet) and so I am trying to set them using this code:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(f'workbook.xlsx', {"nan_inf_to_errors": True})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Column Setter")

worksheet.add_table(f"A1:{chr(ord('@')+len(whole.columns))}{len(whole)}", {'data': 
whole.values.tolist(),
                'banded_columns': True, 'banded_rows': False, 'header_row': True, 
                 'columns': [{'header': col} for col in whole.columns.tolist()]})
worksheet.autofit()
```

However the output seems to set all the column names to Column1 etc.

[image]

This code seems to work perfectly for another dataframe with 3 columns so I'm struggling to understand why this doesn't work. Any answers would be very helpful.

EDIT

I have changed the code to match jmcnamara cpde. It looks as such:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(f'workbook.xlsx', {"nan_inf_to_errors": True})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Column Setter")

(max_row, max_col) = whole.shape

worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1,
 {
    'data': whole.values,
    'banded_columns': True,
    'banded_rows': False,
    'header_row': True, 
 }
)

worksheet.autofit()
```

However this doesn't seem to write the data in at all and just appears with 7 of 26 columns populated. it also doesn't seem to have created a table at all. Please see below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work as expected. Here is an example based on yours with a sample dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some sample data.
data = {}
for num in range(1, 27):
    data[f"Data {num}"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

whole = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a workbook and worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(f"workbook.xlsx", {"nan_inf_to_errors": True})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Column Setter")

# Get the dimensions of the dataframe.
(max_row, max_col) = whole.shape

# Add the Excel table structure.
worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1,
    {
        "data": whole.values,
        "banded_columns": True,
        "banded_rows": False,
        "header_row": True,
        "columns": [{"header": col} for col in whole.columns],
    },
)

worksheet.autofit()

workbook.close()
```

And the output looks like Expected:

[image]

I don't know if it is a factor in your output but it is better to use the (row, col) syntax for the table dimensions rather than trying to construct an A1 style string. Also, the `tolist()` method calls in your example aren't required.

Comment: For some reason it add 7 of the column headers but not the rest and also the data doesn't populate. When I try this for another DataFrame the solution works fine. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: I think the issue may be related to the fact the when I write down the dataframe, it also writes the index row making 27 rows. This extra row spills into row AA so assuming this is an issue. Is there any way to drop index?

Comment: If I comment out the columns parameter the data still doesn't write so seems to be an issue on write

Comment: *"This extra row spills into row AA"*. Your `chr(ord('@')+len()` code doesn't take into account columns above 26 so you should change to using `(row, col)` notation like in my example. All XlsxWriter interfaces take `(row, col)` as well as `A1`. Generally there isn't any point to construct a `A1` reference when you already have the  `(row, col)` data.

Comment: Sorry to explain I was talking about your code. I have switched to the (row, col) reference

Comment: It won't be possible to answer a question about why your code doesn't work unless you post the code that doesn't work. You should edit your initial post to include a **complete** example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I have made the edit to explain and show output

Comment: The edits still don’t show a complete program. If it doesn’t contain any sample data people won’t be able to run the program to see the issue and they won’t be able to say what is wrong with it. Apart from guessing.

Comment: No problem. The data is sensitive data so unfortunately I am unable to share.

Comment: You don’t need to share the data. You can make up a sample dataframe.

Comment: I think I've fixed it. I deleted the file and when re-run it works. Maybe a simple overwrite error. Will accept solution